# How to create certificates on the fly with node http-mitm-proxy library

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I'm using [http-mitm-proxy](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-prox) to intercept Http Requests, but I'm getting this error:

```
"/http-proxy/.http-mitm-proxy/keys/www.google.com.key" missing
"/http-proxy/.http-mitm-proxy/certs/www.google.com.pem" missing
```

I checked and indeed I have the folders `/http-proxy/.http-mitm-proxy/keys` and `/http-proxy/.http-mitm-proxy/certs` but I dont' have those certificates I took a look at this [example](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy#proxyoncertificatemissing--functionctx-files-callback) but it's not clear to me how to create those certificates on the fly. In the documentation it says that I can use `node-forge` to generate them but I'm not sure how to do it. How can I can create certificates on the fly?